# Which character typically separates the text into excel fields

Tags: excel, csv, text, excel-2010, notepad++

comma character (,) typically separates each field of text.
Ex:
`NAME,AGE` -- I will write this in notepad and save it to test.csv
when i opened csv above test automatically separated to each field(Columns) 
Like that  i want to break the text into rows as well
EX:
NAME,AGE Martin,40 Luis,35
but when i save it as test.csv and shoould be look like

```
NAME    AGE
MARTIN   40
Luis     30
```

What isthe  character we should specify to break the text into next line.

Comment: So you want the final result to be a .csv or a .txt file? What you're describing in your post in the comment block would look more like a .txt file.

Comment: Final result be a .csv file only.In the comment block i just specify the Dat format of csv file. simply I can say that are columns and rows.

Comment: What you're posting isn't really a valid CSV file. Why does it have to look like that instead of the usual format of a CSV?

Comment: Simple note , Which character should place between AGE and MARTIN also 40 and Luis that could be break the line when save it from notepad to .csv

Comment: SCENARIO:1
For instance, I started out with this file:
OPEN NOTEPAD WRITE BELOW DATA.
NAME,AGE,LOCATION
I saved it as Test.csv and opened it in Excel. This is what it looks like:
http://postimg.org/image/zboau8qql/

Comment: SCENARIO:2
Again open notepad and write Data below format
NAME,AGE,LOCATION
JOSH,35,USA
I saved it as Test1.csv and opened it in Excel. This is what it looks like:
<img src="http://postimg.org/image/9gtvw684v/">

Comment: SCENARIO:3
SO FINALY MY REQURIMNET IS ,WHEN I WILL WRITE BELOW TEXT IN NOTEPAD
NAME,AGE,LOCATION JOSH,35,USA
AFTER SAVED IT AS TEST2.CSV IT WILL LOOKS LIKE http://postimg.org/image/9gtvw684v/
 WHICH CHARACHTER SHOULD MENTION AFTER TEXT LOCATOIN IN NOTEPAD THEN IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY BREAK THE LINE INTO NEXT ROW IN EXCEL.
 I TRIED WITH NAME,AGE,LOCATION\NJOSH,35,USA. BUT IT DOESN'T WORK

Comment: I still don't understand why it has to be a CSV file. What you're describing is not a CSV. What will you be using this file for?

Comment: it's our requirement to save data into a .csv file. I just what that special character to separate the text into new line automatically when save it to .csv. I have already explained that when we mentioned comma(,) to the text in notepad and save it as a .csv file  then its automatically place into each column.

Answer (score 0):

In a CSV file, commas separate the columns and carriage return/line feeds separate the rows.  It is no more complicated than that.

So, to get your sample data in Excel, save the .csv file so that it looks like:

```
NAME,AGE
MARTIN,40
Luis,30
```

Comment: First i will write it as text in notepad then that save it as .csv file. I need the text sample how to write and what character to specify. I just mentioned that in notepad will write the text like NAME,AGE save it as a .csv and open that file we can see NAME in one column and AGE wlll in one column so comma(,) separates  the text to individual field . in the same way i want to break the text and it will create row in csv.

Comment: @harishkumar Yes. press the enter key (carriage return/line feed) to make a new row.

Comment: @Earp i agree with with enter key. But when have a large text its not possible. which should mention between AGE and MARTIN that will be break the line. Itried with \n but no LUCK

Comment: please have a look on above 2 scenarios

Comment: @harishkumar Why does the length of the text file have anything to do with what character you use?  The only way for Excel to interpret the file in the manner you are describing is to add a new line between each row.  Period.